# React native iOS build issue while upgrading to v0.64.2

Tags: ios, react-native

Trying to build with Xcode 12.4/12.5, React native v0.64.2, Intel MAC

```
error: no such module 'MyWalletSDK'
import MyWalletSDK
       ^
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
        CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/amit/Desktop/MQ/Src/ios/SdkModule.swift
        CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/amit/Desktop/MQ/Src/ios/bridging.swift
        CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
```

Stuck with compilation issues. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by upgrading my wallet SDK from the normal framework to xcFramework compiled with latest swift